# Regex to match exactly 6 digits with any number of spaces between the digits

Tags: javascript, regex, one-time-password

I recently needed to create a regular expression for OTP values in JavaScript. The input should contain 6 digits with spaces any where in between. I am not regex-savvy at all and even though I tried looking for a better way, I ended up with this:

```
/^[\d ]*$/
```

With this I can have spaces with digits but here I don't have control over the number of digits.

Comment: Try `^\s*(\d\s*){6}$`

Comment: `.replace(/[^\d]/g, "").length === 6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let OTPs = [
  "123456", 
  "12345", // Invalid
  "1 2345 6", 
  "1 2 3 4 5 6", 
  "1 2 3 4    5 6",
  "a 2 b 4 5 6" // Invalid
]

let validOTPs = OTPs.filter(otp => otp.match(/^(\d\s*){6}$/g))
     
console.log(validOTPs)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are whitespaces between the numbers.

Comment: OP said "with any number of spaces between the digits", your solution only works for one space. Try with more than one space between the digits :)

Comment: Why are you using a character class for a single "character"? `[\s]*` <==> `\s*`

Answer (score 0):

You also try below regex. See it working at https://regex101.com/r/6rGjOU/1

```
^(\d(\s+)?){6}$
```